# Can system programming be done in JAVA?

Tags: unix, system

Unix System programming to be precise.

Comment: Could you explain more details of what system programming you want?

Comment: It depends by what you mean by 'Unix System programming'. Java can access C libraries through JNI. However, this does not make Java a good candidate for a kernel device driver -- there are a number of factors with a JVM and GC that inhibit Java from being used in this role.

Comment: Someone suggested me Unix system prog. as a good career. So I was wondering in which language it could be done apart from C.

Comment: Java code runs on the virtual machine implementation of the system plattform it is used on. So, my guess would be that since you already need to run a system to run Java, you won't be able to run a system per se using Java. You could possibly run a Java based system on an existing system, but what would be the point of that.

Comment: @Ayush, merchant banking and law are also good careers. Maybe even medicine. If you're just looking for a good career why not do those?

Comment: Hearty thanks to all your answers. I'll consider C for this. 
@My-career-decider : If you don't wanna help then better not comment !

Comment: This is not an appropriate site for career advice. Please see careeroverflow.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using C language, which was originally defined as a language for system software on Unix platforms.